# NameError: name 'print_rows' is not defined

Tags: python, printing, confusion-matrix

Thank you for helping!
I'm training a sound classifier model based on VGG.
I got the original code from apple:'https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/sound_classifier/'.

The error says "NameError: name 'print_rows' is not defined".

I want to print confusion matrix.

I used "print_rows" because I was told in the console:
"You can use print_rows(num_rows=m, num_columns=n) to print more rows and columns."

Anyone knows what is missing? Highly appreciate.

```
import turicreate as tc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mb
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import tqdm as tqdm

from os.path import basename

# Load the audio data and meta data.
data = tc.load_audio('./Desktop/TP/newtracks_wav_cropped')
meta_data = tc.SFrame.read_csv('./Desktop/TP/Tracks/file.csv')

# Join the audio data and the meta data.
data['filename'] = data['path'].apply(lambda p: basename(p))
data = data.join(meta_data)
data

#Drop all records which are not part of the ESC-10.
#data = data.filter_by('True', 'esc10')

# Make a train-test split, just use the first fold as our test set.
test_set = data.filter_by(1, 'fold')
train_set = data.filter_by(1, 'fold', exclude=True)

#print(np.unique(test_set))

# Create the model.
model = tc.sound_classifier.create(train_set, target='situation', feature='audio')

# Generate an SArray of predictions from the test set.
predictions = model.predict(test_set)

# Evaluate the model and print the results
metrics = model.evaluate(test_set)
print(metrics)
print_rows(num_row=52, num_columns=3)

# Save the model for later use in Turi Create
model.save('musicclassifier_apple_1.model')

# Export for use in Core ML
model.export_coreml('musicclassifier_apple_1')
```

Comment: `print_rows()` isn't defined anywhere in the code you've posted, nor is it a standard python function. Is it part of another module or library you've imported? as in `tc.print_rows()`?

Comment: Try model.print_rows(num_row=52, num_columns=3)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of turicreate is a python style of garbage, but you can do it like this:

```
(metrics['confusion_matrix']).print_rows(num_rows=100)
```